# CSS triangle tip not sharp

Tags: css, geometry

I've been using CSS triangles on different websites for about a year now:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid red;
}
```

In Firefox (Mac OS X) the triangles always looked like this:

[image]

Since a couple of days, the triangles look like this in Firefox:

[image]

I don't know exactly since when this happens, I guess since an update to Firefox 24 or 25.

I absolutely prefer how the triangle looked before. Now, the tip looks blunt.

1. What can I do to make the tip sharp again in Firefox?
2. What about other browsers?

Karl

Comment: Not sure this will help, but try 6px instead of 7px

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Windows using FF 25.0, Chrome 30.0 or IE 10.0.

Comment: Same rendering as OP with W7 Fx24, with antialiasing. DLing upate to Fx 25

Comment: re- still the same in Fx25 than in Fx24. Now, what's the problem with a side of 14px made of 2 7px borders? First rendering has a 13px side, seems wrong to me. It may be an happy accident or a desired bug but it's still a bug. And I can only see it when zooming at 800% or more!

Comment: I agree with you, FelipeAls. A 13px side made of two 7px borders can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is how the browser renders it, so there is nothing really you can do besides using images.

Comment: If it changed after an update, you can track down what changed it (if you are willing to dig into the bugzilla logs, and theoretically get some movement on it.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/fb8wW/) to me? What OS are you using? (OSX 10.8.4 here) and Firefox 25.0. Also looks good in Chrome to me (latest version). `Why do you need to have code when adding link to fiddle .__.`

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).

Comment: Tested on another laptop using Mavericks and is O.K. in Firefox. Do you have any plugins that could be causing this?

Comment: If I start Firefox in safe mode (all add-ons disabled), the triangle looks sharp!

Comment: Sounds like an add-on then :) Like I said, I tested firefox 25.0 on mavericks and looks sharp. Try disabling your add-ons one at a time perhaps?

Comment: Very, very strange: If I disable ALL add-ons manually, nothing changes. I have to use safe mode to get a sharp triangle.

Comment: Just done (re-install). Same problem. Are you sure the lower tip of your triangle is only 1px wide? (Did you zoom in?)